# How to append CTE results to main query output?

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I've created a TSQL query that pulls from two sets of tables in my database.  The tables in the Common Table Expression are different from the tables in the main query.  I'm joining on MRN and need the end result to contain accounts from both sets of tables.  I've written the following query to this end:

```
with cteHosp as(
select Distinct p.EncounterNumber, p.MRN, p.AdmitAge
from HospitalPatients p
inner join Eligibility e on p.MRN = e.MRN
inner join HospChgDtl c on p.pt_id = c.pt_id
inner join HospitalDiagnoses d on p.pt_id = d.pt_id
where p.AdmitAge >=12
    and d.dx_cd in ('G89.4','R52.1','R52.2','Z00.129')
)
Select Distinct  a.AccountNo,  a.dob, DATEDIFF(yy, a.dob, GETDATE()) as Age
from RHCCPTDetail c
inner join RHCAppointments a on c.ClaimID = a.ClaimID
inner join Eligibility e on c.hl7Id = e.MRN
full outer join cteHosp on e.MRN = cteHosp.MRN
where DATEDIFF(yy, a.dob, getdate()) >= 12
and left(c.PriDiag,7) in ('G89.4','R52.1','R52.2', 'Z00.129')
or (
DATEDIFF(yy, a.dob, getdate()) >= 12
and LEFT(c.DiagCode2,7) in ('G89.4','R52.1','R52.2','Z00.129')
)
or (
DATEDIFF(yy, a.dob, getdate()) >= 12
and LEFT(c.DiagCode3,7) in ('G89.4','R52.1','R52.2','Z00.129')
)
or (
DATEDIFF(yy, a.dob, getdate()) >= 12
and LEFT(c.DiagCode4,7) in ('G89.4','R52.1','R52.2','Z00.129')
)   
order by AccountNo
```

How do I merge together the output of both the common table expression and the main query into one set of results?

Comment: What do you mean by merge?  Your `cte` and final `select` statement have different columns.  Are you looking to just add the `cte` columns alongside your final output?  If so, just reference them as you would another table.

Comment: I'm looking to merge the CTE results into the main query results. Do I need to name the columns the same?  If so, how do I structure the merge syntax?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by merge?  Please add a desired output into your question.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: If merge means join, then you have to provide data in the CTE that can be related to the main query.  Then you can join the CTE to the main and expose CTE fields in the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge performs inserts, updates or deletes.  I believe you want to join the cte.     If so, here is an example.

Notice the cteBatch is joined to the Main query below.

```
with 
cteBatch (BatchID,BatchDate,Creator,LogID)
as
(
    select 
    BatchID
    ,dateadd(day,right(BatchID,3) -1,
        cast(cast(left(BatchID,4) as varchar(4)) 
        + '-01-01' as date)) BatchDate
    ,Creator
    ,LogID
    from tblPriceMatrixBatch b
    unpivot
    (
        LogID
        for Logs in (LogIDISI,LogIDTG,LogIDWeb)
    )u
)

Select 
0 as isCurrent
,i.InterfaceID
,i.InterfaceName
,b.BatchID
,b.BatchDate
,case when isdate(l.start) = 0 and isdate(l.[end]) = 0 then 'Scheduled' 
             when isdate(l.start) = 1 and isdate(l.[end]) = 0 then 'Running'
             when isdate(l.start) = 1 and isdate(l.[end]) = 1 and isnull(l.haserror,0) = 1  then 'Failed'
             when isdate(l.start) = 1 and isdate(l.[end]) = 1 and isnull(l.haserror,0) != 1  then 'Success' 
             else 'idunno' end as stat
,l.Start as StartTime
,l.[end] as CompleteTime
,b.Creator as Usr

from EOCSupport.dbo.Interfaces i
join EOCSupport.dbo.Logs l
on i.InterfaceID = l.InterfaceID
join cteBatch b
on b.logid = l.LogID
```